# Passing session data in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have stored my logged in session data in php (laravel)session , how can i use same for my angular js controller.

```
 <body ng-app="registerform">
    <p ng-init="userdata={userid:".<?php echo Session::get('userid');?>."}"></p>
  <div id="left-section">
    <div class="header">
      <a href="" class="logo"><?php echo ucfirst(Session::get('username')); ?></a>
      <div class="user-info">
        <a href=""><img src="img/avatar.png"><i class="arrow_box"></i></a>
      </div>

      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="active"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#postJob"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i><span>Post Job</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#viewApplicants"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>View Applicants</span></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i><span>Book</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right-section">
    <div class="header">
      <h5>Header </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="main-data-container">

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

i have just tried this way but got an error, what's the best way to do so.

Comment: Make an ajax call to get the data from a laravel controller

Comment: is that only way? can't we catch the data from view (id/class) as we do with jQuery.

Comment: You can, however I think that would be considered "crappy code"

Comment: you can get the data from server once and store it in service.